# Obtaining family of all curves passing through intersection points of a curve and a line

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections, coordinate-systems

Assuming I have a general conic section $S\equiv ax^2+bxy+cy^2+dx+fy+e=0$ and line $L \equiv px+qy+r=0$, then what will be the general conic passing through their intersection points?

For instance, if I take $S+k \cdot L=0$, then this family of curves will not include all conics as the variable k does not affect the $x^2$, $y^2$ and $xy$ terms.

If I take $S+k \cdot L^2=0$, then this would contain only those curves which are tangent to the original conic section at the points of intersection. (because when we take $S+k \cdot L_1 L_2=0$ it is is the family of curves passing through points of intersection of $S$, $L_1$ and $L_2$. So when $L_1 \equiv L_2$, the curve will be tangent at the points of intersection of $S$ and $L_1$)

Comment: How about $$S+ L(lx+my+n)=0$$

Comment: In your second choice your will get several types of conics depending upon various parameters $a,b,c,f,g,h,p,q,r$.

Comment: For instance $S=x^2+y^2-1=0$ and $ L=x=0$ can give ellipse $ (1+k)x^2+y^2=1$ when $k \ge -1$ and $k\ne 0$.

Comment: @ZAhmed yes, but this ellipse (or hyperbola, when $k<-1$) will always be tangential at the points of intersection of S and L, as you can see here: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/imzxq4yvvf

Comment: Yes your right one may get hyperbola as well, because $k$ is real parameter.

Comment: A conic is defined by 5 parameters, giving two points leaves 3 free parameters: there's no hope to get ALL conics with a linear combination of two equations.

Comment: You might try $$\alpha S+\beta L +\gamma L^2=0.$$